# POSTing variable in a URL string from javascript to PHP (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I've been having trouble passing a variable from Javascript to PHP.  I am working with AJAX for the first time, and the book I'm using instructs me to us the following line of code to post data to my php file:

```
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "CorRex33.php?WriteFridayHours="+WriteFridayHours, true);
```

CorRex33.php is of course my other php file, and WriteFridayHours is my own variable that I'm attempting to move over.  It is defined earlier in the code, as it's passed in the parameters of my function.  I've console.logged it to be sure that there were no issues here.

I will gladly share anything else that helps, but I think I've narrowed it down to the way I'm passing the variable being incorrect somehow. Is there any other way to do this when using AJAX?  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you ever calling `xmlhttp.send()`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#sect1

Comment: Just check your `WriteFridayHours` does have any data. Please Share your full code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending post data in wrong way. You have to append your post data with `send` method. Also you have to set `RequestHeaderset` when you send post data

change your code like below:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "CorRex33.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//Your status change code

xmlhttp.send("WriteFridayHours="+WriteFridayHours);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I have been able to make some progress because of it.  Does the xmlhttp.send need to be received in the CorRex33.php file in any special way, or would it act as normal POST data would?  So I guess what I'm trying to figure out is if ['WriteFridayHours'] can be used and has the value of WriteFridayHours in the javascript file.  Hopefully what I'm trying to say is clear enough. 
 Thank you for any additional help that may be provided.